# Scrolling number counter in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools, unity3d-gui

I want to make a counter that displays a number say 899 and the numbers shift up to go to 900, or more simply 7 scrolls out while the 8 scrolls in.  I know how to make them just change, but I don't know how to do the scroll out effect?

Comment: It is likely going to involve a quite a bit of work, each digit being a ["Scroll Rect"](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-ScrollRect.html), you would likely be better off finding a "Odometer like" control [on the asset store](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/19211).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found this tutorial really helpful in implementing the scrolling number system that you want.

try this 
[tutorial](https://youtu.be/1r_BXVRjXvI), it is really easy to understand.